# homepage url as example.com/ rather than example.com/index.html

Tags: asp.net

I have a site I want to deploy and as part of the finishing touch, I'd like to have the url in the browser show www.example.com/ instead of www.example.com/index.html

How is this done?

Comment: Have you had a look at [Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)?

Comment: you can find solution on this forum
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022949/change-default-startup-page-asp-net-windows-hosted-godaddy

Comment: @Artur The solution in your link changes the default document on the _server-side_, the question here asks how to change on the _client-side_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by "redirecting" requests of one URL (www.example.com) to another URL (www.example.com/index.html). This is done server-side by sending a HTTP 301 (or 302) to the user's browser.

Normally you use so called "rewrite" tools that intercept a request on your webserver and by executing rules that are made out of [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). The rules decide whether/how to redirect.

**Tools**

You could install the [official Rewrite module for IIS](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite), if you are using IIS 7 or above. If you are using IIS 6, you could use the Open Source [UrlRewriter.NET](http://urlrewriter.net/).

Personally, I have very good experiences with both of them, even together inside one single project.

Answer (score 0):

If all that is needed is the default redirect for the website, consider using [httpRedirect](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpRedirect) feature in IIS7\IIS6.